Are there any public medical image databases?
I'm not sure if I'm asking this in the right place, please direct me to the right place for me to ask this if I am not.
I'm working on a project to look at images of the inner ear from an otoscope and for it to tell whether the ear is healthy or has an ear infection. I tried going to MedPix and Open-i to search for images but they haven't been very helpful. Outside of these I'm struggling to find a database to train my model, does anyone know where else I could look?
